# CDMA basic working principle

Tags: communication, signal-processing, mobile, telecommunications, code

I find it hard to find on the internet a simplified explanation of the principle of operation of the CDMA system. Could you give me an example of how it works and how a receiver can correctly identify a user's message?

Precisely, as I understand it, each user sends a certain message, often called spreading code, which is composed of a series of pulses called chips.

For example, the spreading codes of two users may be:

User 1: 1, 1, -1, -1

User 2: -1, -1.1, -1

I read on the internet that each user has a personal code, which is chosen to ensure orthogonality to avoid interference. However it is not specified which sequences must be orthogonal: orthogonality between the spreading codes, orthogonality between the personal code of a user and those of the other users, orthogonality between the personal code of a user and the spreading codes of other users?

Comment: orthogonality between all of those you mentioned. It's quite easy to generate systematically 1000s of orthogonal (or nearly orthogonal, which is good enough for the application) codes, check out [Gold code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_code) as one way of doing this. I don't know whether any particular CDMA system like IS-95 uses this method, but it's one method, and there others.

Comment: what must be orthogonal? certainly before the bit-recovery process, the correlation (using analog or DSP methods) must have been performed. For lowest power, where must the correlation be performed?

Comment: Back in the university we have learned this stuff using this textbook: https://www.amazon.ca/Computer-Networks-Andrew-S-Tanenbaum-ebook/dp/B006Y1BKGC And I am not suggesting anything, but I saw some links for downloads around...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orthogonal (or nearly orthogonal) means essentially that the convolution between two codes does not peak significantly, so someone decoding with a different code will get a low average signal power.  From there, you'll probably have to take a math class.